# An enigmatic pattern in division graphs

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, visualization

Draw the numbers $1,2,\dots,N$ on a circle and draw a line from $n$ to $m>n$ when $n$ divides $m$:

[image]

For larger $N$ some kind of stable structure emerges

[image]

which remains **perfectly in place** for ever larger $N$, even though the points on the circle get ever closer, i.e. are moving.

[image]
[image]

This really astonishes me, I wouldn't have guessed. Can someone explain?

---

In its full beauty the case $N=1000$ (cheating a bit by adding also lines from $m$ to $n$ when $(m-N)\%N$ divides $(n-N)\%N$ thus symmetrizing the picture):

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Note that a similar phenomenon – stable asymptotic patterns, esp. cardioids, nephroids, and so on – can be observed in [modular multiplication graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001178/visualizing-rational-numbers-as-multiplication-graphs) $M:N$ with a line drawn from $n$ to $m$ if $M\cdot n \equiv m \pmod{N}$.

For the graphs $M:N$, $N > M$ for small $M$

[image]

But not for larger $M$

[image]

For $M:(3M -1)$

[image: ![![enter image description here]

It would be interesting to understand how these two phenomena relate.

---

Note that one can create arbitrary large division graphs with circle and compass alone, without even explicitly checking if a number $n$ divides another number $m$:

1. Create a regular $2^n$-gon.
2. Mark an initial corner $C_1$.
3. For each corner $C_k$ do the following:

   4. Set the radius $r$ of the compass to $|C_1C_k|$.
   5. Draw a circle around $C_{k_0} = C_k$ with radius $r$.
   6. On the circle do lie two other corners, pick the next one in counter-clockwise direction, $C_{k_1}$.
   7. If $C_1$ does not lie between $C_{k_0}$ and $C_{k_1}$ (in counter-clockwise direction) or equals $C_{k_1}$:
   8. Draw a line from $C_k$ to $C_{k_1}$.
   9. Let $C_{k_0} = C_{k_1}$ and proceed with 5.
   10. Else: Stop.

---

There are three equivalent ways to create the division graph for $N$ edge by edge:

1. For each $n = 1,2,...,N$: For each $m\leq N$ draw an edge between $n$ and $m$ when $n$ divides $m$.
2. For each $n = 1,2,...,N$: For each $k = 1,2,...,N$ draw an edge between $n$ and $m = k\cdot n$ when $m \leq N$.
3. For each $k = 1,2,...,N$: For each $n = 1,2,...,N$ draw an edge between $n$ and $m = k\cdot n$ when $m \leq N$.

Comment: Very pretty.  The envelopes stay in place because each corresponds to connecting angle point $\theta$ (measured anticlockwise from the bottom) to angle point $k\theta$ for given integer $k \ge 2$ and all possible  up to $0 \lt \theta \le \frac{2\pi}{k}$.  For given $N$ you only get lines when $\theta =  2\pi \frac{n}{N}$  and $0 \lt n \le \frac{N}{k}$, but that has little effect on the envelopes.

Comment: @Henry. Thanks! Can you tell if the "main" envelope is a half cardoid?

Comment: Yes it is: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid#Cardioid_as_envelope_of_a_pencil_of_lines) this is a result of Luigi Cremona

Comment: More interesting to me are the cusps and why they occur.  They seem to lie on the line joining angle point $\frac{\pi}{k-1}$ to $\frac{k\pi}{k-1}$.  I suspect that they may be parts of epicycloids - specifically $\frac1k$ of an $k-1$  cusp epicycloid so for example the second envelope is a third of a nephroid

Comment: @Henry: If you don't mind, please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Rephrasing, these curves are arising as the envelopes of pairs of numbers whose division gives $2,3,4,...$, hence the resemblance to cardioids, where the second coordinate "moves faster" than the first. With some care you can probably also show a much lower density of near-perpendicular curves through each cardioid,

Comment: @AlexR.Could you please elaborate your last phrase: "show a much lower density of near-perpendicular curves through each cardioid"? Which graph do you refer to?

Comment: @AlexR.: You  might want to have a look at the "answer" I give below.

Comment: The third way to create the division graph is the same are the second, when we rename $n\leftrightarrow k$.

Comment: This reminded me of [a video of Matologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhbuKbxJsk8) on youtube - maybe related.

Comment: @M.Winter: Not by accident. This video gave me a lot of inspiration. I should give credit to Burkard Polster every now and then.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Not quite the same when it comes to the order in which edges are created - which of course may be neglected. (Note that the first to ways create the edges in the same order.)

Answer (score 8):

To add some visual sugar to Alex R's comment (thanks for it):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Putting the pieces together one may explain the pattern like this:

- The division graph for $N$ can be seen as the [sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphSum.html) of the multiplication graphs $G_N^k$, $k=2,3,..,N$ with an edge from $n$ to $m$ when $k\cdot n = m$. When $n > N/k$ there's no line emanating from $n$. (This relates to step 7 in the geometric construction above.)
- The multiplication-modulo-$N$ graphs $H_{N}^k$  have a weaker condition: there's an edge from $n$ to $m$ when $k\cdot n \equiv m \pmod{N}$.
- So the division graph for $N$ is a proper subgraph of the sum of multiplication graphs $H_{N+1}^k$.
- The multiplication graphs $H_{N}^k$ exhibit characteristic $k-1$-lobed patterns:

[image][image][image]

- These patterns are truncated in the graphs $G_{N}^k$ exactly at $N/k$.
- Overlaying the truncated patterns gives the pattern in question.